C# for Excel VSTO add-in in Visual Studio - Load selected cell formula to User Control (Windows forms)
I'm working on an VSTO add-in for Excel, I'm using Visual Studio and C#, and I'm stuck at something that should be simple enough, but no online documentation gave me a working answer.
I'm stuck at loading the formula from the selected cell to a textbox ("txtValue") from a User Control (Windows forms).
I added the triggers, I process the formula into a string S , everything that I have right now works, until the part where I need to load a simple string variable to the textbox "txtValue" from the User Control ctrlFormulas
//I call the code below using:
clsControls.update("Formulas", "txtValue", formattedFormula.ToString());

//
        internal static void update(string formName, string controlKey, string S)
        {
            switch (formName)
            {
                case "Formulas":
                    // Access the user control and update the textbox
                    var userControl = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new ctrlFormulas(), formName);
                    //var tableLayout = userControl.Control.Controls["tableLayoutPanel1"] as TableLayoutPanel;
                    var textBox = FindTextBoxRecursive(userControl.Control, "txtValue");

                    if (textBox != null)
                    {
                        textBox.Text = S; // This updates the value of textBox.Text, but does not update the User Control
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }

        private static TextBox FindTextBoxRecursive(Control parentControl, string targetName)
        {
            foreach (Control control in parentControl.Controls)
            {
                if (control.Name == targetName && control is TextBox textBox)
                {
                    return textBox;
                }

                if (control.HasChildren)
                {
                    var childResult = FindTextBoxRecursive(control, targetName);
                    if (childResult != null)
                    {
                        return childResult;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

I defined the controls so they toggle on and off in a separate class
    internal class clsControls
    {
        private static string WBCtrlName;

        private static ctrlFormulas cFormulas;
        private static Tools.CustomTaskPane tpFormulas;

        public static Tools.CustomTaskPane ControlToggle(Tools.CustomTaskPane tpTEMP, string controllName)
        {
            //IF IT'S ALREADY INITIALIZED
            if (tpTEMP != null)
            {
                //IF SHEET CHANGED, REINITIALIZE
                if (WBCtrlName != Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name)
                {
                    tpTEMP=ControlInit(controllName);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tpTEMP.Visible == true)
                    {
                        tpTEMP.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tpTEMP.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                //IF NOT INITIALIZED, THEN INITIALZE
                tpTEMP = ControlInit(controllName);
            }

            return tpTEMP;      
        }
        public static Tools.CustomTaskPane ControlInit( string controllName)
        {
            Tools.CustomTaskPane ctrlTemp=null;
            WBCtrlName = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name;

            switch (controllName)
            {               
                case "Formulas":
                    ctrlFormulas cFormulas = new ctrlFormulas();
                    ctrlTemp = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(cFormulas, controllName);
                    ctrlTemp.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft;
                    ctrlTemp.Width = 500;
                    ctrlTemp.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
            return ctrlTemp;

        }

I initialize the user controls like below:
    public partial class RibbonMain
    {
        private void btnShowFormulas_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            clsControls.toggleFormulas();
        }
    }

Please let me know if you need more information, I can't share the whole project as it has some sensitive information.
